# Adding Custom Objects To The Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, image-processing

Folks here is the concept i have in my mind. I have a face and i want to check how different hair styles look on the person. Now suppose that that i have the image of a face that has been separated from a picture through image segmentation. Now how can i make something like this that the user can select a hair style and i place that on the head of the person. Its like whatever hairstyle he will select it would be adjusted onto the face. Now this is the thing that i want to achieve. I am totally blank how will i put this thing up in my application. Kindly guide me through with detailed answer. Much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), place two [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)s one overlaying another. Then set the bottom one image to a had image and set the top one image to a hair image(it must be a .png file with fulll opacity except where actually hair is).